# GSM arduino to webservice not working

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I have setup a arduino with a SIM300 based GSM board. I have

> Tx of Arduino connected to the Rx of GSM board
>
> Rx of Arduino connected to the Tx of GSM board
>
> Gn of Arduino connected to the Gd of GSM board

The GSM has a Vodafone 3g sim, activated with 3g. The GSM board has 2 LED's, one remains `ON` and the other blinks ever 4-5 seconds. Which I guess means that its configured to work with the SIM.

I then run the following code.

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Serial ports initialized");
 
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CGATT=1");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\",\"0.0.0.0\",0,0");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CDNSCFG=\"8.8.8.8\",\"8.8.4.4\"");
   delay(1000);
   Serial.println("AT+CSTT=\"TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\",\"\",\"\"");
   delay(2000);
   Serial.println("AT+CIICR");
   delay(5000);
   Serial.println("AT+CIFSR");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CDNSORIP=1");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"http://myec2DNS-us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:myportnumber/mywebservice/myreques/Authentication/Request?identity=somecode&identityType=sometype\",\"myportnumber\"");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND");
   delay(500);
   Serial.println("AT");
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

On cutecom I get te following

```
Serial ports initialized
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET","0.0.0.0",0,0
AT+CDNSCFG="8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"
AT+CSTT="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET","",""
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CDNSORIP=1
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","http://myec2DNS-us-compute.amazonaws.com:8080/myservice/mycommand/Authentication/Request?identity=%somecode&identityType=1","8080"
AT+CIPSEND
AT
```

When I run `tail -f  /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/localhost_access_log.2014-09-20.txt' on my webserver, I get nothing from the arduino.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are using the wrong serial interface. I see `Serial` and `mySerial`.

After `mySerial.begin()` you write to `Serial`, not to `mySerial` which runs on pins 10 and 11.

What's when you send the AT Commands from your Serial connection to the Arduino? It Should redirect them to the GSM board.

Comment: I welcome your answer. Shouldn't the `loop` method take care of that ? I did also get OK's for all AT commands.

Comment: The `loop()` redirects incoming commands from `Serial` to `mySerial` and vice versa.  If i'm not mistaken the AT Commands in `setup()` are sent to your computer and not to the GSM module. Where does the OK's come to?

Comment: The OK's come on the `cutecom ttyUSB0`. I think its working that way.

Comment: You might want to implement error handling for the AT commands.
Though if you believe this answer has fixed your question press the ✔ below the ⇩ on the left side of the question.